# sync mongo collections to elastic search using mongo-connector

Tags: python, mongodb, elasticsearch, replication, mongo-connector

I want to sync mongo collections to elastic search using mongo-connector. created the replica-set and trying to sync the data. getting few issues. below versions used so far.
mongo 4.4
elastic search 7.15

Followed the below blog for development.
https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-ElasticSearch

Comment: I'm not sure that `mongo-connector` is compatible with ES 7.X, the project seems to be dead/stalled and there is some issues asking for support for [elasticsearch 7.x](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/issues/888).

Comment: You might want to try using Debezium + Elasticsearch sink. Then, when you have a Kafka cluster, you can have your apps write to Kafka first, rather than Mongo directly